# Ionic useditems(items); ReferenceError: useItems is not defined

Tags: ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

I got an error while testing out if it loads, but I got this error while trying "ReferenceError: useItems is not defined", anyone knows what is the problem?

```
//JS
function MyController($scope, $http) {


$scope.items = [
{imgsrc: '../img/tgtprofilepic.png', name: 'lala9', address: 'asdasd, Singapore 199123', time:'Open Now (08:00AM - 9:00pm)', featuredimg:'../img/list2.jpg', desc:'asddasdsddsadsadasd' }, 
{imgsrc: '../img/tgtprofilepic.png', name: 'lala10', address: 'asdasd, Singapore 199321', time:'Open Now (08:00AM - 9:00pm)', featuredimg:'../img/list2.jpg', desc:'asddasdsddsadsadasd' }, 
{imgsrc: '../img/tgtprofilepic.png', name: 'lala11', address: 'asdasd, Singapore 199123', time:'Open Now (08:00AM - 9:00pm)', featuredimg:'../img/list2.jpg', desc:'asddasdsddsadsadasd' }];
  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $http.get('/more-items').success(function(items) {
      useItems(items);
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    });
  };

  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.loadMore();
  });
};

//in html
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="item in items">

        <div class="item item-avatar">
          <img src="{{item.imgsrc}}" alt="">
          <h2>{{{{item.name}}}}</h2>
          <p>{{item.address}}</p>
          <p><span class="operationStatus"></span>{{item.time}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-body">
          <img class="full-image" src="{{item.featuredimg}}" alt="">
          <p>
            {{item.desc}}
          </p>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function called `useItems()` in the following code:

```
$http.get('/more-items').success(function(items) {
      useItems(items);
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
});
```

However, there is no `useItems()` function anywhere in the code you have posted. Perhaps you have forgotten to add this function?

Comment: no I dont have a useItems function, actually I got from here what can I do about this useItems() though?

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/

Comment: Have you tried removing the useItems() function from your code and tested whether it achieves what you are trying to do? A lot of functions in the example code you have shared are not present, probably so you can fill them in yourself.

Could you perhaps share what you are trying to do with this code? Because you have code for infiniteScroll in your controller, but you don't seem to be utilizing it in your HTML.